# Extract download link from yt-mp3 Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, flask, extract

I am trying to extract the download link from `yt-mp3` with Python for my project but I could not find it.

Here is my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

#http://www.yt-mp3.com/watch?v=cXAxpoC8o9w

url = "http://www.yt-mp3.com/watch?v="+"cXAxpoC8o9w"#YT video ID
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}


req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
website = urllib2.urlopen(req)

html = website.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href',None)
    if link is not None:
        print link
```

Comment: Print out the returned HTML, there are no `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The website has been designed to make it difficult to extract the link text you are trying to get. As such, using `urllib2` or `request` is not going to help.

To get around this problem, you would need to use something like `selenium` to automate a webbrowser. In this case you need to automate hovering over the download button. It is this action that allows the link to be seen.

This could be done as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.yt-mp3.com/watch?v=cXAxpoC8o9w")
time.sleep(6)
download = browser.find_element_by_class_name('download')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(download).perform()
print "MP3 link is", download.get_attribute("href")
```

Further improvements could be made to remove the `sleep()`.

This would display something like:

```
MP3 link is http://dl13.yt-mp3.com/download/tom-clancy-s-rainbow-six-vegas-2-gameplay-part-3.mp3?id=cXAxpoC8o9w&title=Tom+Clancy%27s+Rainbow+Six+Vegas+2+gameplay+part+3&t=1457899780&extra=a&h=75c5c580bf5c2791725b392d5b6cfcc75d8dd272
```

Comment: i'm using Cloud9 to run this and it isn't working , so any other solution ?? and Thank you.

Comment: The problem is, you will need something to run the javascript in the page. I've not checked if it makes further requests after loading. This might give you a clue.

Comment: Doesn't Cloud9 also support Selenium testing? Worth investigating.